# Apply function to one element of tuple in Scala

Tags: list, scala, tuples

I'm using Scala and I have a tuple (String, List[Int]) like this:
`("tom", [1,2,3])`

I need to apply a function to the second element of this tuple and to return a list of tuples. Say, I want to multiply the elements in the list by 2, so the output should be:
`[("tom", 2), ("tom", 4), ("tom", 6)]`

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As @Luis says, the idea is that you use `map`.

First you get your list out of the input tuple. Here's one way to do it.

```scala
val name, values = ("tom", List(1,2,3))
```

Next you iterate over that list. For each element, you convert it into a new tuple with a constant name and the value multiplied by 2.

```scala
val result = values.map(x => (name, 2*x))
```